# Making fine tictactoe lines with html and css

Tags: html, css

Trying out hands on front end design with simple Tic Toc Toe game application. Unfortunately, CSS does not make the lines very accurate and generated gaps between each block. Any aesthetic suggestion please to make make the design beautiful and coherent?

I tried to look Mozilla MDN community for MODEL-BOX concept, but did not get my solution.

```css
h3 {
  text-align: center;
}

td {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
}

#td11 {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

#td13 {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

#td22 {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#td31 {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

#td33 {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h3>Tic Tac Toe</h3>
  <table align="center">
    <thead></thead>
    <tr>
      <td id="td11"></td>
      <td id="td12"></td>
      <td id="td13"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="td21"></td>
      <td id="td22"></td>
      <td id="td23"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="td31"></td>
      <td id="td32"></td>
      <td id="td33"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Refer this link https://github.com/vasanthk/tic-tac-toe-js

Comment: Any particular reason why you're not using CSS grid layout for this?

Comment: @TylerH, new into CSS design, so not able to apply some deep concept. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want CSS's [border-collapse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse) property.

**EDIT** I should add that this solution will only address the *specific* problem of the gaps in the `<table>` cell borders.

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```css
h3 {
  text-align: center;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
}

#td11 {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

#td13 {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

#td22 {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#td31 {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

#td33 {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h3>Tic Tac Toe</h3>
  <table align="center">
    <thead></thead>
    <tr>
      <td id="td11"></td>
      <td id="td12"></td>
      <td id="td13"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="td21"></td>
      <td id="td22"></td>
      <td id="td23"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="td31"></td>
      <td id="td32"></td>
      <td id="td33"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this one:

[TicTacToe](https://codepen.io/xunnn/pen/yEmMbm)

HTML:

```
<h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="vert"></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="hori"></td>
        <td class="vert hori"></td>
        <td class="hori"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="vert"></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
td {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
table {
  margin: 5px auto;
}
.vert {
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  border-right: 2px solid black;
}
.hori {
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a better design by adding these properties to the table itself.

```
<table align="center" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1"></table>
```

Comment: Mail, did not work the solution, as it adds in every element a border around it. !

Answer (score 0):

You should include the folowing code in your css:

```
   *{
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
    }
```

Maybe this solves your problem.

Comment: 13, it makes my Grids on left side. Sorry but did not work successfully. !